# Overlay a div and have it fade away after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I need this div to be overlayed over a much more complex website on load, and fade away when  is clicked, like a welcome splash screen of sorts. I've had a good look at others resposes and I'm not quite understanding the jquery side of it. Unfortunately I dont have enough experience in it. I got an image overlayed that disappeared on click, however this div has a separate div with an enter image that fades in and out with webkit, so using the whole div is what I'm struggling to achieve. heres my current layout (minus the more complex site)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper_index">
<div id="enter_button"> <a href="home.html"><img src="images/enter_button.png" width="138" height="50" class="withfadein"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper_index {
    height: 686px;
    width: 1024px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-image: url(images/entry_image-01.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
#enter_button {
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 434px;
    top: 501px;
}
.withfadein{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: load 20s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load{
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
.withfadein2{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: load 10s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load{
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
.withfadeout { 
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
} 
.withfadeout:hover { 
-webkit-opacity: 0.25; 
-moz-opacity: 0.25; 
opacity: 0.25; 
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Make the `div#wrapper_index` disappear when user click on it?

Comment: @LeBen yea when you click on div id="enter_button", which is overlayed div#wrapper_index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this relatively easily with jQuery and you can forget all the CSS animation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/p6vKU/

JS:

```
$('#enter_button').on('click', function () {
    $('#wrapper_index').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Copied your demo over perfectly and the way it interacts with the other content is stuffing it up, would it be possible for me to send you an offline version? It's a big ask but the help is really apprciated

Comment: Sure no probs, get my email from the description here http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033